# How to concatenate three files (and skip the first line of one file) an send it as inputs to my program?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

There are file A, B, C.
I want to concatenate file A, B and C (Skip first line of C).
And then send them to myProgram as input.
How can I write this in shell script?

I wrote that

```
cat A > file
echo >> file     //want to start all contents in new line
cat B >> file
tail -n+2 C >> file
./myProgram < file
```

But I have no idea how to concatenate them and send to a program without generating a file

Comment: I love these questions because there's always eight more ways to solve the problem than I would have thought of.

Answer (score 12):

Try this :

```
{ cat A ; echo; cat B ; awk 'NR>1' C ; } | programm
```

puttings commands inside *curly brackets* is *grouping*.

Not that the `;` is mandatory if there's no newline to finish the *grouping*.

And no need a another *subshell* here ;)

Comment: You don't need to specify a subshell (i.e. with `()` instead of `{}`), but since the command grouping is part of a pipeline, your shell may choose to use one anyway.

Comment: Another subshell if you prefer

Comment: No need for `awk` - you can use `tail -n+2` to skip the first line :)

Answer (score 6):

Using process substitution

```
./myProgram < <(cat A; echo ''; cat B; tail -n +2 C)
```

`<(commands)` creates a fifo file that is then read into the program

You can test by doing

`$ echo <(cat A; echo ''; cat B; tail -n +2 C)
/dev/fd/63`

> Process Substitution
>         is supported on systems that support named pipes
>          (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.  It takes the  form
>          of  <(list) or >(list).  The process list is run with its input or out-
>          put connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd.  The name of this file
>          is  passed  as  an argument to the current command as the result of the
>          expansion.  If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will  pro-
>          vide  input  for list.  If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as
>          an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.
>          When available, process substitution is performed  simultaneously  with
>          parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic
>          expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Use a subshell. Run the commands in a subshell and pipe the output to your program.

```
(cat a; echo; cat b; tail -n+2 c) | ./myProgram
```

Comment: Why the subshell ? Not required at all

Comment: AFAICT it's needed since OP wanted the echo command. Your answer didn't include that command.

Comment: POST edited accordingly, still no subshell

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware of the { and } functionality a.k.a. group command. Thanks for telling me/us.

Comment: From bash man page:
{ list; }
              list  is  simply  executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as a group command.

I'll go with the 'group command' name :)

Comment: Subshells let you skimp on whitespace and semicolons, thats likely the biggest effect in this...

Comment: Avoid subshells when not strictly needed to avoid side effects: `( x=1 ); echo $x` Answer must fits OP needs but also future users coming here from a google search

Comment: In a pipeline you can't reliably avoid subshells.  See the last paragraph of [POSIX Shell Command Language section 2.12](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12).

Answer (score 4):

```
tail -n +2 C | cat A <(echo) B - | myProgram
```

Here you tell `tail` to read from line 2 onwards and pass it to `cat` which will concatenate in order A+B+STDIN(-) then pass it to myProgram.

Edit:
Added the newline between A and B.

Comment: Seems complicated for a simple task...

Answer (score 3):

awk approach

```
awk 'ARGIND<3;ARGIND==3&&FNR>1' a b c | ./myProgram
```

Comment: Note: ARGIND is not POSIX

Comment: (@StevenPenny) the traditional `awk '!flag || NR>1' a b flag=1 c` method^Whack is POSIX

Answer (score 2):

Some more possibilities:

```
{ grep -h "^" A B ; { read; cat; } < C ; } | ./myProgram
```

- `grep "^"` matches the start of *every* line, even if the last line doesn't end in a newline.  `-h` prevents grep from prefixing each match with the filename it is from.
- `read` reads (and discards) the first line of C, then the `cat` gives the rest of C.

---

Or purely with `sed`:

```
{ sed "" A B ; sed "1d" < C ; } | ./myProgram
```

Comment: Definitely no need for two `sed`s: `sed -e '1{r A' -e 'r B' -e 'd;}' C | runstuff` With `ed` you don't even need the pipe: `ed -s C <<<$'1r B\n1r A\n1d\n,w ! runstuff\nq'`